# custom confirm using jQuery and asp.net web forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm just new in front-end so I have may be a silly question.
I have a button

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="bt_stop" ID="bt_Stop" OnClick="bt_Stop_Click"></asp:Button>
```

I want to ask user if he wants to proceed this event.

```
   <div id="pad_confirmation">
       <span>Are you sure?</span>
        <input id="ok" type="submit" value="OK" />
        <input id="cancel" type="reset" value="CANCEL" />
    </div>
```

Like in common confirm form, but I need my own interface for confirmation window. I dont want to use any plugins or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might need a javascript confirm box. You can find a simple tutorial here
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp
and here is the demo
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm
I hope this will help you

Comment: Yes, but I need to implement my own interface for this window @peter-darmis

Comment: You mean customize it regarding css? If yes then this post might help out http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1385

Comment: I use asp.net web forms. Unfortunetely this post is about php back-end.  @peter-darmis

Comment: Just use the dialog.js and the css from that demo. Basically you need to run the dialog.js during the onclick event of your button <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="bt_stop" ID="bt_Stop" OnClientClick="javascript:CustomAlert()"></asp:Button>

Comment: they use ajax at last((( I think that there is more simple method @peter-darmis